# CakePHP Upload: Behavior not detected

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload

I am using this
[image uploader](https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload)

After following the installation instructions, I am getting this problem:

[image]

This is my folder structure (manually installed):

[image]

As you can see, UploadBehavior.php is already created, and the content is the same as the one on Git, with the UploadBehaviour class defined.

I also loaded the plugin on Config/bootstrap.php as usual

```
CakePlugin::load('Upload');
```

And also on the model

```
public $actsAs = array(
    'Upload.Upload' => array(
        'foto' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'dir' => 'foto_dir'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

I have no clue of what is going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly it's a permission issue, try installing the plugin via git or changing permissions with chmod if you're using linux

Comment: Yes, it was that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. As the file was there but it wasn't able to access it I modified the permissions so that every user can access it.. 
I also needed to change to 777 the app/webroot/files app.

Maybe creators of this plugin should warn about this.